# RegEx to match end of string

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to match e-mail addresses in a text document for which I am writing a regex. I have come up with something like this for starters -

```
((?:[a-zA-Z]+[\w+\.\-]+[\-a-zA-Z]+))[ ]*((?:@|at))[ ]*(?:[a-zA-Z\.]+)
```

I want to make sure that the end of the e-mail address is a 'edu' or 'com'. How do I do this? I am using Python.

Some sample e-mail addresses from my text document

```
alice @ so.edu
alice at sm.so.edu
alice @ sm.com
```

Edit -

I want to make a change to this regex ONLY. My regex fits a few other examples in my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((?:[a-zA-Z]+[\w+\.\-]+[\-a-zA-Z]+))[ ]*((?:@|at))[ ]*(?:[a-zA-Z\.]+)\.(com|edu)
```

**EDIT**: For a "dot" instead of ".":

```
((?:[a-zA-Z]+[\w+\.\-]+[\-a-zA-Z]+))[ ]*((?:@|at))[ ]*(?:[a-zA-Z\.]+) *(\.|dot) *(com|edu)
```

Comment: Why is the '$' not needed? Because - (?:[a-zA-Z\.]+)\. gets through the whole domain/sub-domain thing right? Just want to confirm if I have understood it correctly.

Comment: @mcenly Hm, I don't see a `$` in your regex or mine. A `$` would match only e-mail addresses at the end of a line. That may or may not be what you want. In your sample document with only one e-mail per line, I don't think it matters at all, but in a text document with e-mails sprawled throughout, a `$` would cause only those e-mails at the end of a line to be matched.

Comment: by end of line you mean \n right and not end of string? Sorry to bother you on this.

Comment: @mcenley Yes, that's what I meant!

Comment: I also have e-mails of the pattern 'alice @ bob dot com' in my dataset. The mentioned regex won't work then right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/180174) for explanation of how to match *all* valid e-mail addresses as per RFC822.

I would personally not modify the regular expression, but use `email.Utils.parseaddr()` on the regexp matches instead and check that the resulting string `.endswith("edu")` or `.endswith("com")`. E.g.

```
>>> email.Utils.parseaddr("kimvais@mailinator.com")[1].endswith(".com")
True
```

Comment: Would it not work if he has spaces and `at` instead of `@` in his e-mail addresses?

Comment: @Kimvais I can't - reason being there are complex ways people have written their e-mail addresses to avoid spam.

Comment: @mcenley - fair enough. However, please note that there is a _huge_ amount of e-mail addresses that do __not__ end with `.edu` or `.com`

Comment: @Kimvais I have a list of TLDs with me.